# Генерация и обновление html страницы на java

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование

Сделал приложение на Java, оно периодически генерирует данные, а теперь появиласс необходимость отображать эти данные в формате веб-сайта, причем при обновлении данных они должны изменяться и на открытой в браузере странице без необходимости ее перезагрузки. От верстки и вообще фронт-энд разработки я далек, поэтому хотелось бы простого и понятного решения.
Ранее использовал `ktor framework`, но не нашел на нем возможности динамически обновлять страницу.

Comment: Книгу [Head First Servlets and JSP](https://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Servlets-JSP-Certified/dp/0596516681/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1524589489&sr=1-2&keywords=servlets+and+jsp) в руки и вперед! Коротко: вам нужно изучить сервлеты, JavaServerPages и понять, для начала, что такое веб контейнер.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, понятия "HTML-программирования" нет, во вторых вам нужно подучить JavaScript чтобы нормально реализовать задумку, а точне `DOM`, `Ajax`, если вы не плохо знаете Java, вам не составит турда изучить эти технологии для реализации этой задумки.

Comment: Понятия JabaScript тоже нету:)

Comment: Ух, спасибо, не заметил.